# What are the most active Ruby forums/blogs on the web?

Tags: ruby, user-forums

I have just spent 2 days with Ruby, and my observation in last two days is that it is very difficult (as compared to say .NET/Java) to find an active forum/blogs which are helpful for Ruby (or maybe I don't know them since I am new).

Which are the most common forums/blogs developers visit when they need help with Ruby (other than Stack Overflow)?

Answer (score 9):

Some of your best bets are the following IRC channels on irc.freenode.net. Very active.

#rubyonrails

#ruby-lang

#ruby

You can almost always get questions answered in minutes. There is an etiquette to follow, and they can get cranky if you don't follow it, but I think mostly that's because some of the main responders are sitting there for hours answering question after question and they want you to phrase things in a way that allows them to be efficient.

Here are some good blogs:

[errtheblog](http://errtheblog.com/)

[Jamis Buck's blog (author of Capistrano, works for 37 Signals with DHH)](http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/)

Answer (score 4):

The ruby-talk mailing list can be helpful and gets between 70-100 messages a day.

http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/community/mailing-lists/

Answer (score 1):

RailsCasts are fantastic if you're doing Rails.

For just plain Ruby, I just google and find things for the most part.

Answer (score 1):

There are so many Ruby Blogs that I won't list them here. [www.ruby-forum.com](http://www.ruby-forum.com) has lots of posts, and if you are after rails stuff [www.railsforum.com](http://www.railsforum.com) is pretty active, [www.pragprog.com](http://www.pragprog.com) has lot's great ruby books for sale, including Programming Ruby, widely accepted as the first book to learn Ruby with, for better or worse. RubyInside, RufyFlow are great but a good list of blogs at [Ruby Learning](http://rubylearning.com/blog/2009/03/12/50-ruby-related-blogs-to-read/) website and if you need Ruby API docs [Ruby Brain](http://www.rubybrain.com), and if you are doing Rails then [Rails Brain](http://www.railsbrain.com) is good too, although really I have had not rouble turning up Ruby stuff just by searching Google, but stuff should keep you going for a while.

Answer (score 1):

Shameless plug, but here's a good resource: http://www.postrank.com/topic/ruby

Answer (score 0):

I'll add a couple of blogs that I think are mandatory for any person really interested in Ruby:

[One Step Back](http://onestepback.org/index.cgi)
[has_many :through](http://blog.hasmanythrough.com/)
[On Ruby](http://on-ruby.blogspot.com/)
[Igvita](http://www.igvita.com/)

There are many more personal blogs that I personally consider interesting but these 4 are good for anyone interested in the language itself.

Besides this, ruby-talk / ruby-forum are good places to hang out and if you
need any help you can always access #ruby-lang in irc.freenode.net

Answer (score 0):

You can look at these links:

- http://rubylearning.com/
- http://www.railsenvy.com/
- http://rubyflow.com/
- http://peepcode.com/
- http://www.rubyinside.com/
- http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/
- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/
- http://www.digitalmediaminute.com/article/1816/top-ruby-on-rails-tutorials

Answer (score 0):

For Ruby on Rails, I prefer 
http://www.workingwithrails.com/

If you have any RoR question you can use "Ask a Rails Expert" forum and if you want to discuss with other RoR developers you can partcipate in the "Rails in the workplace" forum.

Hope this helps.

[http://www.workingwithrails.com/]http://www.workingwithrails.com/